# SQL: Rank ordered query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am in Access 2010 and am trying to create a rank or row number field for a query which is ordered in a specific way. I have tried `Rank: DCount("id","[Query1]","id <= " & [id])` but it ignores my Query's sort, since the order is NOT as the ID Primary Key.

Comment: How about posting a small section of data - just cut and paste, do not worry too much about layout - and some notes on the order that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen your sorting logic and it seems that I managed to produce a rank based upon it, by creating an additional query (Temp), with a column containing all the sorting function subproducts concatenated in it. The code for this query should look like this:

```
SELECT Table1.Code1, 
    Len(Mid([Code1] & "",1,IIf(InStr([Code1] & "","*")>0,InStr([Code1] & "","*")-1,Len([Table1].[Code1] & "")))) 
    & Mid([Code1] & "",1,IIf(InStr([Code1] & "","*")>0,InStr([Code1] & "","*")-1,Len([Table1].[Code1] & ""))) & 
    Val(Mid([Code1] & "",InStr([Code1] & "","*")+1)) & 
    CStr(Val(Mid([Code1] & "",InStr([Code1] & "","*")+1))) AS OrderCode1
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Len(Mid([Code1] & "",1,IIf(InStr([Code1] & "","*")>0,InStr([Code1] & "","*")-1,Len([Table1].[Code1] & "")))), 
    Mid([Code1] & "",1,IIf(InStr([Code1] & "","*")>0,InStr([Code1] & "","*")-1,Len([Table1].[Code1] & ""))), 
    Val(Mid([Code1] & "",InStr([Code1] & "","*")+1)), 
    CStr(Val(Mid([Code1] & "",InStr([Code1] & "","*")+1))), Table1.Code1;
```

After that, if you create a query over this additional one, and use the `DCount` function with the 'OrderCode1' column on the `WHERE` parameter, you should get a sequential rank. Something like this:

```
SELECT Temp.Code1, DCount("Code1","[Temp]","OrderCode1 <= '" & [OrderCode1] & "'") AS Rank
FROM Temp;
```

If you are still needing a solution for this, you can check if it works!

Comment: My query has a complex string sort. [REF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494240/sql-sort-and-filter). I tried the following `Rank: DCount("Id","[qryMaterialSortLast]","Sort1 <= " & [Sort1] & " and Sort2 <= '" & [Sort2] & "' and Sort3 <= " & [Sort3] )` but didn't work for some.

Comment: I had tried to do something similar to sort but was having hard time with the second sort level as it houses a string. Using your post, I came up with the following, which sorts out pretty well given my fields and don’t need to use the DCount function on another query:
`OrderCode1: Len(Mid([Code1] & "",1,IIf(InStr([Code1] & "","*")>0,InStr([Code1] & "","*")-1,Len([Code1] & "")))) & Mid([Code1] & "",1,IIf(InStr([Code1] & "","*")>0,InStr([Code1] & "","*")-1,Len([Code1] & ""))) & Len(CStr(Val(Mid([Code1] & "",InStr([Code1] & "","*")+1)))) & CStr(Val(Mid([Code1] & "",InStr([Code1] & "","*")+1)))`

Comment: I just added len() for what’s after the asterisk. That way it sorts better
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderID) AS RowNo, OrderID FROM Orders
```